Conditionally wrap a vue 3 element
In Vue 3, how can an element be conditionally wrapped rather than creating two seperate blocks with v-if directive?
I have a simplified example here, but the question deals with conditional wrapping. There are a few issues here, in the html block there is a lot of coupling with state in the script setup block, so abstracting that to a child component is more trouble than it's worth. There would be mixed state and it would be a mess having to deal with emitting data from child to parent. Second, because of the size of the html block, creating manual render functions would also be a mess.
The below code does work, but there is a big block that is duplicated just because I need an extra wrapper. Note that this question is not about how css could be used to fix this.
<script setup>
const isMobile = ref(true)
</script>

<template>
  <div v-if="isMobile" class="mobile-wrapper">
    <div class="product-meta">
      <!-- long html block tightly coupled with script setup block -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div v-else class="product-meta">
    <!-- same html block -->
  </div>
</template>


Sounds like a xy problem. If you want to reuse the html block/logic/code/states/etc, put it in a component. Why not just add the "mobile-wrapper" class based on isMobile?

It‘s more complicated than that, this would require a lot of props to be passed into the child, and would require the child to emit events which I don‘t see as a good tradeoff

I thought of adding the div class="product-meta"></div> to the code and only wrapping it if isMobile is true, but I can‘t seem to use a template ref in a vue render function.

I know it is not wrapping but want to note that <component> element can be handy for some cases. Just make content of :is attribute conditional with desired wrap element or simple div. (template won't work)
<template>
  <component
    :is="isLink ? 'a' : 'div'"
    :href="linkUrl"
  >
    <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/5a7f9ab641cb0ba66833a41f263e09c4?s=256&d=identicon">
  </component>
</template>

Note: Instead of a and :href, RouterLink and :to works as well.
